# AWS S3 not showing images on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I built a rails app and set up s3 and paperclip together. So far, the images are being posted into my s3 account. But on the live app it's not actually showing the image and just showing the broken file icon.

Any ideas why this is happening? Is it a paperclip error? is it Heroku? Is it my controller?

Here's the live app: http://petaluma-marin.herokuapp.com/Nutrition-Recipes
Here's my repo: https://github.com/Gcamara14/Recipe_app

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url to the images is wrong.  The URL for your second image currently is this

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/recipe-app-gio/recipes/images/000/000/009/medium/Screen_Shot_2017-05-30_at_1.19.49_PM.png?1496243164
```

What it needs to be is this

```
http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/recipe-app-gio/recipes/images/000/000/009/medium/Screen_Shot_2017-05-30_at_1.19.49_PM.png?1496243164
```

Notice instead of `http://s3.aws...` at the beginning you need `http://s3-us-west-1.aws...`

Whenever I have issues with S3 I find it is easiest to go to the bucket and look at the path and then inspect the image or asset and see if they match.

Comment: Thank you for showing me two versions of the link. It really helped me visualize this. Great way to show an error... thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

To give you a hint about what the issue might be, in your browser if you copy/paste the url for a photo you should see this message:

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

Take a look at your [paperclip_defaults](https://github.com/Gcamara14/Recipe_app/blob/27a55aa5570dfe119751c388d3cfc95a07567bf2/config/environments/production.rb#L81). You are missing the `s3_host_name` that would contain something like `s3-us-west-1` (as mentioned in one of the prior answers).

Also looks like there is an issue already created in the `paperclip` repo that should help you out ([here)](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2151).

Comment: The way you explained this was really well. Thank you so much for providing me the resource and the github issue!!